# No reply from potential supervisor of my dreams: is it OK to try meeting them in person?

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions, graduate-school, advisor, biology

After much research at many universities, I have found a supervisor whose research perfectly matches my research interests. I believe that I have truly found a good match...and believe that I would also be a great addition to the research team given my background and goals etc.

I have not heard back from said professor...it has only been a few days, and I intend to send follow up emails in the future. However, I am wondering, should I never hear back (because this has happened with other potential supervisors), do you think it would be OK to try and meet with this person physically? Said supervisor is at a university I have never been to, and in the UK (I live in the US), and I can't really find their office hours online nor classes they may be teaching. Any advice on how to get in touch with them in person, if I am willing to travel and go that extra mile? I would normally drop it, but I am so set on this one.

Comment: Maybe I am special about this, but if you travelled uninvited from the US to England just to come to plea with me in person for a PhD student position, I would not be impressed but *scared as hell*. Send a mail, send a follow-up, and if you hear nothing from him then, *drop it*. It also does not sound overly healthy for you to be so set on a single potential advisor - you should be aware that the probability that it won't work out with him is much higher than the opposite.

Comment: @xLeitix I think you should turn this into an answer. It's the right answer, after all.

Comment: The phone is a powerful tool.

Comment: @xLeitix: Yeah, that only works in romantic comedies.

Answer (score 17):

Some important things to know:

1) Many professors receive *dozens* of unsolicited emails a day from potential graduate students, and essentially ignore them because they can't keep up (although having a form letter "no more students!" response is, perhaps, a nicer thing to do).

2) Many (most) faculty don't admit students without having some idea of how they will fund them, so it's not unlikely that this specific researcher can't really offer you a spot in the department.

3) In my experience, most of the unsolicited emails are also way off the mark in terms of research topics, so the most important part of your communication with this researcher is conveying that you a) actually know what they do, b) have something useful to offer, and c) that you are applying to the department and would like to work with them. And it's fine to ask to speak with them *briefly* (by email or phone) about whether you would fit in with their research plans.  They might ignore you.

If you are actually in the area and want to set up a meeting (by email), that's one thing, but I don't think you should fly to their country and ambush them.

Not to be a downer, but just because you think this person is the perfect advisor doesn't mean that you are their perfect student (or that they want another student right now).  That said, you can still send a nice follow-up email and apply.  You might want to apply to some other places too, however.

Comment: I think this answer about sums up all of the reasons why I have at times not answered similar emails :-)

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth agreed. This is an excellent response.

Comment: I try to answer all emails I get, even if briefly. Sometimes, I may forget. However, I am very selective in who I take on. Do not put all your eggs in one basket. There is not the *one* supervisor, as there is not the *one* possible partner (and the latter relation is expected to be longer-lived).

Answer (score 3):

Your proposed plan is weird and inadvisable (as others have said).  Without any context, to them you are simply one more person on the street. If there is sufficient funding for them to take students then they probably also have more people interested in working with them than they can take. If they have limited or no funding they can access, they will need to be careful about who they take. In either case, their time is precious to them.
If you want to meet them in person, you should do so through a mutual contact, or by attending a conference they are (speaking) at (I appreciate that without being on a PhD program this may be difficult, but you seem to have money to spare anyway).

A more normal approach would be to simply apply to their institution, and say (if given an appropriate option) that you would like to work with that supervisor.

However, you need to consider the difference in culture. If you are looking to start a PhD in the US, you are very likely not yet ready to apply for PhDs in the UK. The likely reason you can't find their office hours online is that many UK institutions don't have office hours.

Answer (score 2):

I have one anecdote that is worthy of mention and consideration here. An ambitious colleague of mine really wanted to get a better supervisor. To do this, he traveled to an Ivy league university, arranged meetings with all relevant staff (some of whom were famous enough that I knew them by name even though I am not in his field). This audacious move paid off as he was accepted at this university (unofficially) as part of the research lab of one of the most well respect researchers in his field. This relationship and associate turned out to be of great benefit to him.

While this story doesn't discount what dang said above, I think it shows how travelling to meet face to face with potential supervisors can be a much more effective way of getting them on board then emailing them. What is important, give what xLeitix said, is that you should not signal desperation by making it known that you travelled all that way to meet that person - instead, just explain your travel for other reasons.

Comment: I think the key here is "arrange a meeting". If they agree, that is perfectly all right; but just showing up is weird at best (and chances are the office is behind locked doors).